# GCS to BQ load with hardcoded values for columns

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have created a big query table with a schema through browser tool. Next time I am appending a csv to that table through API calls from my local using python. But that csv don't contain all columns that I already specified in the schema. For ex, my file contains columns A,B and C while the schema contains columns A,B,C and D. Is there a way to hardcode the value of D while appending the file to the table?

I am out of ideas here.

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas

You might want to check the "mode" of data columns when you define them.

**Nullable: Column allows NULL values (default)**

**Required: NULL values are not allowed**

If you have created your columns using the "REQUIRED" mode and if you have missing columns while loading then execution will error out for sure.

Let's say you have: A,B,C,D as 'required' columns
and you send:
1,2,3
Your loading job will definitely complain.

Also, one more thing to make sure about missing columns data, after making them nullable:
If you have A,B,C,D columns as nullable and if you want to skip data for B and C, you will still need to send like this in your load job as:
1,,,4

In this case, B and C values for the above row will be set to null.

Also, another things to note in any load job:
Ref: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationLoad

Especially these 4 fields: skipLeadingRows, maxBadRecords, ignoreUnknownValues, allowJaggedRows

For your case of **missing trailing columns**, you need to set: **allowJaggedRows** as well.